# json.dumps with indent prints different output

Tags: python, json

This might be a silly question but I am quite new using json, and I do not fully understand this:

(Using [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_python_compiler) online compiler)

```
import json
print("Hello World")
print(json.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], separators=(',',':')))
```

As far as I've understood: **json.dumps takes an object and produces a string**

And the output seems right:

`[1,2,3,{"6":7,"4":5}]`

I searched for a way to make it more readable, and there is a parameter called `indent`that does the job well. But I do not understand why the output is different.

`print(json.dumps([1,2,3,{'4': 5, '6': 7}], indent=2, separators=(',',':')))`

Output:

```
[                                                                                                                              
  1,                                                                                                                           
  2,                                                                                                                           
  3,                                                                                                                           
  {                                                                                                                            
    "6":7,                                                                                                                     
    "4":5                                                                                                                      
  }                                                                                                                            
]
```

Shouldn't it be first `"4":5, "6":7`and not the other way around?

(Expected result?)

```
  [                                                                                                                              
      1,                                                                                                                           
      2,                                                                                                                           
      3,                                                                                                                           
      {                                                                                                                            
        "4":5,                                                                                                                     
        "6":7                                                                                                                      
      }                                                                                                                            
    ]
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `Yes, the order of elements in JSON arrays is preserved`, but if I understood it correctly (I might be wrong, quite new to json), the order here is not preserved! @MikeScotty

Comment: The order of elements in an array ([]) is maintained. The order of elements (name:value pairs) in an "object" ({}) is not.

Comment: The order of object keys in JSON / JS is not preserved (nor is it important), which is also answered in the linked question. Neither is the order of dictionary keys in python prior to 3.6 (where it first became an implementation detail). Optionally, you could use ``sort_keys`` in your [dumps](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/json.html#json.dumps), which will sort the keys alphabetically in the output, but still the order will not be preserved.

Comment: Okay thank you! Should I delete de question? Or mark it as a duplicated? @MikeScotty